# Is it possible save images separate from the record they are used in inside CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swiftui, cloudkit

I want to let users of the app create posts for a feed but I want to store post images separate to speed up load times.  Is it possible to store images in one record and then fetch them along with the post that they belong to at the same time that I fetch the post? If so how would I implement this in SwiftUI?

I have already figured out how to save/fetch post just not images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly do this. I'm going to assume your `recordType` is a `Post` that has the content for an item in your feed.

I can think of two options. Regardless of what approach you take, you should be storing your images as `CKAsset` on CloudKit.

**== Option 1 ==**

You can have a field on a `Post` that is of type `Asset List` and load it up with `CKAsset` records which will be your images. When you access each `CKAsset`, it gets downloaded after you have the original `Post` record. This is probably the cleanest approach.

**== Option 2 ==**

Make another `recordType` called `Image` and it could have a field of type `Reference` (a `CKReference`) back to a `Post`. So as each `Image` is created, it gets assigned a `Post` and points to it.

When you query for your `Post` records, you also query for all the `Image` records that are connected to the `Post`. This could be done like this:

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Image", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "post = %@", CKRecord.Reference(recordID: CKRecord.ID(recordName: yourPostRecordName), action: .deleteSelf)))
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
  
var images = [CKRecord]()
operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
  //Load up all the images
  images.append(record)
}

operation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
  //All the image records have been downloaded, or there was an error
}

yourContainerDatabase.add(operation)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.